# Replace accented character in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I had a script or Ruby, and when I try to replace accented charcater `gsub` doesn't work with me :

my floder name is `"Réé Ab"`

```
name = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
name.downcase!
name.gsub!(/[àáâãäå]/,'a')
name.gsub!(/æ/,'ae')
name.gsub!(/ç/, 'c')
name.gsub!(/[èéêë]/,'e')
name.gsub!(/[ìíîï]/,'i')
name.gsub!(/[ýÿ]/,'y')
name.gsub!(/[òóôõö]/,'o')
name.gsub!(/[ùúûü]/,'u')
```

the output `"réé ab"`, why the accented characters stil there ?

Comment: It worked for me with hard-coded name. What happens if you substitute `name="Réé Ab"` as the first line (which will ensure everything is in same encoding)? What version of Ruby are you running, what is output if you do `p [name.encoding, __ENCODING__, Encoding.default_external]` on second line (giving you encoding of the dir string, the script and how Ruby will try to read file system)?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/rRop8O), what is the encoding?

Comment: Mac OS X? Anyway, if it's Unicode (UTF-8 for example) then try [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) `name` ([built-in since 2.2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS-2.2.0#L82-L84) otherwise you have to use a gem).

Comment: the encoding is UTF-8

Comment: @Euphor08: What does `name.bytes` return?

Comment: name1 = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
       name="#{name1}"

I try this but alwys the same problem !

Comment: name.bytes return this [97, 45, 101, 204, 129, 101, 204, 129]

Comment: Yep, the regex uses `é` (`[195, 169]`) but `name` uses `é` (`[101, 204, 129]`). What's your Ruby version (`p RUBY_VERSION`)?

Comment: this is my ruby's version : ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `é` in your `name` are actually two different Unicode [codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point): [U+0065](https://codepoints.net/U+0065) (`LATIN SMALL LETTER E`) and [U+0301](https://codepoints.net/U+0301) (`COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`).

```
p 'é'.each_codepoint.map{|e|"U+#{e.to_s(16).upcase.rjust(4,'0')}"} * ' ' # => "U+0065 U+0301"
```

However the `é` in your regex is only one: [U+00E9](https://codepoints.net/U+00E9) (`LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE`). Wikipedia has an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) about Unicode equivalence. The [official Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) also contains explanations and information about this topic.

How to normalize Unicode strings in Ruby depends on its version. It has [Unicode normalization support](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/unicode_normalize/rdoc/String.html) since 2.2. You don't have to require a library or install a gem like in previous versions ([here's an overview](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/benchmarking-ruby-unicode-normalization-alternatives/)). To normalize `name` simpy call `String#unicode_normalize` with `:nfc` or `:nfkc` as argument to compose `é` (U+0065 and U+0301) to `é` (U+00E9):

```
name = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
name.unicode_normalize! # thankfully :nfc is the default
name.downcase!
```

Of course, you could also use decomposed characters in your regular expressions but that probably won't work on other file systems and then you would also have to normalize: NFD or NFKD to decompose.

I also like to or even should point out that converting `é` to `e` or `ü` to `u` causes information loss. For example, the German word Müll (trash) would be converted to Mull (mull / forest humus).